# Next js static export unstyled html flash with css module files. [FOUC]

Tags: css, next.js14, fouc

I am working with next.js and everything seems to be fine when I am using app with npm run dev.

But when I am exporting my next.js app to a static files with command npm run build and trying to open my project for part of the second the screen is unstyled, this cause very bad user experience.

Im using latest version of Next.js (14.1.1)

Currently I'm importing important parts dynamically and using inline css to fix the problem. However, I would like to just use the css module files.